# Using the .NET Email API, how do I add an image and then have the ability to decide/determine its placement/location within the email?

Tags: c#, .net, email

I would like to add an image as an attachment to an email and then have control over where the image is actually placed within the email, either by overriding the html to be rendered, or by some other means.  Is this possible?

Comment: I am using the System.Net.Mail API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at

[How do I embed images in an email?](http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/4.4.aspx)

Comment: I'll accpet that.  I had just bloody been to that page and skimmed over that quickly I missed it. Thanks.

Comment: I overlooked using a HTML file with keywords, this would have meant I had complete control over complete email look and feel.  Also overlooked XML and XSLT for this purpose too....Wood forvtrees spring to mind,,,

Answer (score 0):

i had a small sample of code that will do something like this

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("file path here");
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
.......[continue with method here]..........
```